# Is there a generalized form of the chi squared divergence?

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, divergence

Usually the chi squared divergence is used to compare two distributions. But is there a generalized form that also to compare k distributions?
Intuitively I would consider to calculate the chi squared divergence of each distribution to the mean of all distributions.